# How to Schedule Local Notification Once in a Day at Random Time With Random Text

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I Want Random Local notification once every 24 hours.
   I know , i Can have Daily Local Notification Using this :

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];  
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
localNotification.alertBody = alertText;
localNotification.alertAction = alertAction;    

// Schedule it with the app

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[localNotification release];
```

But ,With This I can Have Same Time Every Day ,But How can I have a Random Time EveryDay.
 Please Help !

Even, Is this Possible ?

Comment: localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;    This Line Will Fire Local Notification Every Day On same Time ,But I want At Random Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [UILocalNotification class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you could schedule up to 64 local notifications to fire at exact time. It is enough to cover a couple months of random timed notifications since every app launch. Here is a sample:

```c
- (void)scheduleLocalNotifications
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    static NSInteger dayInSeconds = 60*60*24;
    NSInteger now = (NSInteger)[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSInteger tomorrowStart = now - now % dayInSeconds + dayInSeconds;
    for (int q=0; q<64; ++q)
    {
        NSInteger notificationTime = tomorrowStart + q*dayInSeconds + rand()%dayInSeconds;
        NSDate * notificationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:notificationTime];
        NSLog(@"date %@", notificationDate);

        UILocalNotification * notification = [UILocalNotification new];
        notification.fireDate = notificationDate;
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notification.alertBody = @"Hello!";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank U .So This Will Fire Every Time When App Launch ! n It will get Schedule Every Time i launch app ??   & if So , u mean i have To reschedule it after 64 days if App not getting Launched in this Time Interval...

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed I mean you should reschedule all 64 notifications after every launch. This will keep notifications firing 64 days after the last launch. Just don't forget to cancel previous notifications before scheduling new ones.

Comment: Ya I got It. Thanks. I am Doing Same. But i am Failed To set on Every Day With Your This line NSInteger notificationTime = tomorrowStart + q*dayInSeconds + rand()%dayInSeconds;  Sometimes , i got Two Notifications on same day ... Can u please Guide on this !  i Want Only one Notification per day ..

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed Make sure you cancelling previously scheduled notifications and not setting `repeatInterval` for notifications. I've edited my answer to contain a complete method that will do all the job and log fire dates of notifications. It surely shows only one notification per day.

Comment: Yea Its Working . & ya , i am Cancelling all previously scheduled Notifications.  Thank You .

Comment: heii One more Thing :  When i log My Scheduled Notifications Then i Found Some Of them are on same Date , i am Doing NSLog like this :  UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];    NSArray *oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

    NSLog(@" Scheduled Local Notifications : %@",oldNotifications);

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed Got it. Just needed to set `timeZone` of notifications to GMT. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking to do this in Swift you can do something like this:

```
func scheduleNotfications() {
        print("Scheduling reminder notifications")

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()

        let windowInSeconds: UInt32 = 60*60*5
        let oneDayInSeconds: Double = 60*60*24
        let windowAroundHour = 14

        let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
        calendar?.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

        if let todayAtWindowHour = calendar?.dateBySettingHour(windowAroundHour, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: NSDate(), options: .MatchFirst)?.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate {
            for index in 1...48 {
                var notificationDate = ( todayAtWindowHour + ( Double(index) * oneDayInSeconds ) )

                // either remove or add anything up to the window
                if arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 {
                    notificationDate = notificationDate + Double(arc4random_uniform(windowInSeconds))
                } else {
                    notificationDate = notificationDate - Double(arc4random_uniform(windowInSeconds))
                }

                let fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: notificationDate)

                let notification = UILocalNotification()
                notification.alertBody = NSLocalizedString("You've received a new notification.", comment: "Notification")
                notification.fireDate = fireDate
                notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
                notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

                print("Set for: \(fireDate)")
            }
        }

        print("Finished scheduling reminder notifications")
    }
```

The above will schedule random notifications for the next 48 days, making sure those notifications only fire at a reasonable time of the day.

You can call this from applicationDidBecomeActive()

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0   
     scheduleNotfications()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Clean answer**

This schedules a notification for the next 64 days. Good place to set it is in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` because it `cancelAllLocalNotifications` and set 64 notifications for the future. So every time the user opens the app it clears and reschedule for the next 64 days from now.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

NSDate *givenDate = [NSDate date]; // set your start date here
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:givenDate];

NSDateComponents *dateComps = [NSDateComponents new];
[dateComps setYear:components.year];
[dateComps setMonth:components.month];
[dateComps setDay:components.day];
[dateComps setHour:components.hour];
[dateComps setMinute:components.minute];
[dateComps setSecond:0];
NSDate *notificationDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++) {
    UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
    [notification setFireDate:notificationDate];
    [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [notification setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];
    [notification setAlertBody:@"My notification body!"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

    notificationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:86400 sinceDate:notificationDate];
}
```

Output:

```
...
[26] Date : 2016-06-29 17:11:00 +0000
[27] Date : 2016-06-30 17:11:00 +0000
[28] Date : 2016-07-01 17:11:00 +0000
[29] Date : 2016-07-02 17:11:00 +0000
...
```